# What are the priorities when assigning IPs?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

When deploying `dnsmasq` in order to server both DNS and DHCP I have a hard time understanding the priority of various settings.

The network, DHCP-wise, is composed of various devices:

- the ones which advertise their hostname
- the ones which do not and I need to access them (know their IP upfront)
- the ones which do not but I do not care about the IP they will get

My usual approach was to have two groups of devices: the ones I fix an address for (via their MAC) and the ones which get whatever is available (and volatile).

`dnsmasq` seems to offer another approach: to have an IP assigned based on the hostname. I therefore would have the following cases:

#### Devices not defined anywhere in the config files which offer their hostname and get an IP.

Will these also be automatically registered/available in the DNS part of `dnsmasq` so that I can `ping host1.example.com` without knowing its IP, just its hostname?

#### Devices which do not advertize a hostname and present in `/etc/hosts`

Would these get the IP defined there? Or do I need to also set a `dhcp-host=` entry in `dnsmasq.conf`?

I am asking because I got a message suggesting so when starting `dnsmasq`:

```
not giving name rpi2 to the DHCP lease of 10.100.10.212 because the name exists in /etc/hosts with address 10.100.10.202
```

Yet, `rpi2` received `10.100.10.212` (which is exactly what `dnsmasq` said it would not give). Or is this just a warning that `/etc/hosts` defines an IP which does not match the one which will be actually assigned by DHCP?

---

Or is `/etc/hosts` a strictly DNS reference and is not used ever in DHCP assignment decisions?

Answer (score 0):

> My usual approach was to have two groups of devices: the ones I fix an
>   address for (via their MAC) and the ones which get whatever is
>   available (and volatile).

dnsmasq configuration line for binding hostname, IP address and MAC for DHCP:

```
dhcp-host=88:88:88:88:88:88,192.168.0.123,uncle-tompkin
```

Hostname must also be in /etc/hosts for DNS:

```
192.168.0.123   uncle-tompkin.trickster.gods uncle-tompkin
```